(wacom) Setting a smaller active area, I don't want the area outside to receive touch and pen input
I use xsetwacom to rotate the pad, upper half for touch, lower half for pen, since my palm constantly interferes with the pen when touch and pen uses the same area.
Question: how to disable input outside the set area?

Expected: No pen input when the pen is above 10824.
No touch input when touch is below 10823.

Reality: Pen input above 10824 = moving cursor horizontally along top-most of the screen, as if the touch area is compressed into a horizontal line.
Touch input below 10823 = moving cursor horizontally along bottom-most of the screen, as if the stylus area is compressed into a horizontal line.


script: https://pastebin.com/BP2Tm2u2
Linux kernel 5.15.0-102-generic
libinput 1.20.0
Wacom tablet model: CTH-661  Bamboo Fun
xsetwacom 1.0.0


orientation="CCW"    # portrait, buttons on top
activearea="10824 0 21648 13700"    # lower half
activetoucharea="0 0 10823 13700"    # upper half
 
xsetwacom set "$WACOM_STYLUS" Rotate "$orientation"
xsetwacom set "$WACOM_TOUCH"  Rotate "$orientation"
 
xsetwacom set "$WACOM_STYLUS" Area "$activearea"
xsetwacom set "$WACOM_TOUCH"  Area "$activetoucharea"


#                CCW: Buttons on top        x,y=0,0
# +-----------------------------------------------+
# |                                               |
# |    +-------------------------------------+    |
# |    |                                     |    |
# |    |                                     |    |
# |    |                                     |    |
# |    |              Touch                  |    |
# |    |                                     |    |
# |    |                                     |    |
# |    |                                     |    |
# |    +-------------------------------------+    |
# |    10823,13700                                |
# |                                    10824,0    |
# |    +-------------------------------------+    |
# |    |                                     |    |
# |    |                                     |    |
# |    |                                     |    |
# |    |              Stylus                 |    |
# |    |                                     |    |
# |    |                                     |    |
# |    |                                     |    |
# |    +-------------------------------------+    |
# +-----------------------------------------------+
# 21648,13700


documentation Input outside of these coordinates will be clipped to the edges of the area defined.  I think there's no cure.
